# Running an executable from python code

Tags: python, system, exe

I am trying to run create a codebook from a database of images using [colordescriptor.exe](http://koen.me/research/colordescriptors/readme). The code comes with an python scirpt which is actually a scirpt to create a codebook. In the usage example it says thath I have to run the following command to console: `python exampleCreateCodebook.py trainimages.txt outputFilename`, where trainimages.txt a list of dataset images and outputFilename the name of the output codebook. When I tried to run the command (from the dir that the .exe is located) I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "exampleCreateCodebook.py", line 112, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
File "exampleCreateCodebook.py", line 109, in main
return process(options, args)
File "exampleCreateCodebook.py", line 80, in process
raise Exception("Error when executing '%s': command returned error" % cmdLine)
Exception: Error when executing 'colorDescriptor.exe C:\sift\fashion1\00010big.jpg --keepLimited 30 --outputFormat binary --output c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\tmp9qzldd --detector densesampling --ds_spacing 6 --ds_scales 1.2 --descriptor opponentsift': command returned error
```

How can I run properly the exampleCreateCodebook? Is there a chance I am gettting problems due to os.system function? The scirpt file is the [following](https://github.com/vdel/BMVC10/blob/master/libs/colordescriptors/exampleCreateCodebook.py). I have noticed that my program fails in line 80 since returnCode is equal to -1. Thus it seems that `os.system(cmdLine)` doens't run properly. I tried to change the above command with `returnCode =subprocess.call(['cmd', '/k', cmdLine] )`. When I did so the scirpt was iterate just one time inside the for loop and it stops after the subprocess.call. Is subprocess responsible for stoping the for-loop?

```
for inputImage in inputImages:
    cmdLine = "%s %s --keepLimited %d --outputFormat binary --output %s %s" % (binarySoftware, inputImage, keepLimited, tempFilename, extractionConfig)
    print cmdLine
    subprocess.call(['cmd', '/k', cmdLine] )
    print 'ole'
```

List inputImages contains 1000 images. However the for loop stops after first iteration, at the first call of subprocess.

Comment: What if you execute the command directly from command line, without involving Python at all?

Comment: For loop is just part of the code, which creates a dictionary from local features which are calculated for every image inside for loop. When I try to execute the command from console it runs properly. However, I am trying to find a solution in order to use exampleCreateCodebook script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the output that you've shown correct? It doesn't look like it's been copied verbatim.

Looking at the [example Python code](https://github.com/vdel/BMVC10/blob/master/libs/colordescriptors/exampleCreateCodebook.py), it is not possible for the exception to be raised at line 80 **and** for line 82 to be executed.

If by some miracle it is executing line 82, the `IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument` would be happening if the output file generated by `colorDescriptor.exe` is less than 4 bytes long. This would likely be the case when the `colorDescriptor.exe` fails as it has during your run. Lines 84-85 of `DescriptorIO.py`:

```
identify = f.read(4)
f.seek(-4, os.SEEK_CUR)
```

Looks like a bug where it is assumed that the file will have at least 4 bytes. If it doesn't `seek()` will fail with `IOError`.

You need to work out why colorDescriptor.exe is failing. Try running the program manually and you might discover the source of the problem:

```
colorDescriptor.exe C:\sift\fashion1\00010big.jpg --keepLimited 30 --outputFormat binary --output    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\tmpywsquy --detector densesampling --ds_spacing 6 --ds_scales 1.2 --descriptor opponentsift
```

N.B. I altered the above command removing the spaces in `--   keepLimited` because that's what the code should generate. If it really is generating spaces in the command, that might be the problem.

Comment: When I run the program from terminal it worked fine. When I change the os.system to sybprocess.call, it executes just one time the .exe, it created one temporal local features and it stops. However when i tried the code as it is reurnCode was equal to 1. I thnk that I got an error on the output code.

Comment: In the terminal, did you run the _exact_ command in the same directory? Does the file `C:\sift\fashion1\00010big.jpg` exist and can it be opened by the exe? I don't think that this is a problem with `os.system()`. It's probably something to do with the exe, the generated command, or the image files (location and/or permissions).

Comment: @JoseRamon: the traceback makes more sense now.

Comment: I have noticed that when I try to run a simple example of code with subprocess.call: for file in onlyfiles:
    subprocess.call(['cmd', '/k', pattern] ) //pattern an echo. I manage to run it only one from terminal. When I call python file from terminal. However with sublime it runs it properly(len(onlyfiles) times).

Comment: I want to run the following: `cmd ='/snap/bin/tesseract'
for file in files:os.system(cmd) #arguments;file tempfile` A bin programme in a directory loop with the file argument. In bash it is easy, just call the bin, but here...?

Comment: @Timo: probably you would be better off using  [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=popen#using-the-subprocess-module) to execute your command with arguments.

Comment: @mhawke, thanks, there is pytesseract, so this python wrapper made subprocess useless for positive.